# is there any way to not to capture logs for a particular api using properties file?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

I don't want to make any code change.

I want to make change in configuration. Currently I'm using below code to restrict api from printing in logs.

```
if (log.isInfoEnabled() && !!(request.getRequest().startsWith("abc"))) {
logRequest(request, request.getRemoteAddr());
}
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
logRequest(request, request.getRemote());
}
```

Comment: Which logging system?

Comment: all log system can filter per package, so you can specify wich level of logging to log per package and where log into. The problem is that `request.getRequest().startsWith("abc")` I dont think is possibile to make via configuration.